# Issue Connecting to RDS Endpoint with EC2 Instance through EB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sequelize.js, rds

I am having an issue with my Elasticbeantalk environment where the EC2 instance is not allowed to connect to my RDS instance. I can't seem to determine why this might be because I configured the RDS security group to allow MYSQL connection for any IP and have the same inbound rule in my EC2 instance security group. I tested my endpoint connection from my command line with `nc -zv test-db.cffvlzfsdafasf6x7kir.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306` and `I Connection to ... succeeded!` as a response, which indicates there isn't an issue with my security group on the RDS instance, but in my EC2 instance log I have `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`.

Here is my connection via Sequelize and I checked the username and password for my environment variables, which I confirmed are correct:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.LOCAL_DATABASE, process.env.RDS_DATABASE || process.env.LOCAL_USERNAME, process.env.RDS_USERNAME || process.env.LOCAL_PASSWORD, process.env.RDS_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT || '3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
```

Any suggestions of a checklist that I should perform or where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Your RDS_HOSTNAME should be test-db.cffvlzfsdafasf6x7kir.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com and not local host

Comment: right, but won't it option to use the `process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME` since it is present in my EC2 instance and referenced before the `||`?

Comment: If you want to connect to RDS why are you using || statement?

Comment: I have an env variable set within my EC2 instance, so this is being used for production, but I left in 'localhost' because I want to use that db when I run local tests. I do not have an env variable set within my local app repo. Would this make a differencet?

Comment: I am not sure about that but your EC2 is trying to connect to local DB instead of RDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is all wrong:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.LOCAL_DATABASE, process.env.RDS_DATABASE || process.env.LOCAL_USERNAME, process.env.RDS_USERNAME || process.env.LOCAL_PASSWORD, process.env.RDS_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT || '3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
```

You somehow managed to put a `||` where you needed to put a `,` and a `,` where you should have put a `||`. Try this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.LOCAL_DATABASE || process.env.RDS_DATABASE, 
        process.env.LOCAL_USERNAME || process.env.RDS_USERNAME, 
        process.env.LOCAL_PASSWORD || process.env.RDS_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT || '3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
```

Comment: thank you for catching my biggest problem. There were no issues after this change.